# How does Heisenberg uncertainity principle apply here?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg's uncertainity principle states that we can't mutually determine both the trajectory and momentum of a subatomic particle. BUT when dealing with moving charges and magnetism we do problems with the charge in electromagnetic fields. the path is sometimes cicular, helical, cycloid etc.

Consider an electron fired with a velocity $v$. We know its path in a perpendicular magnetic field is a circle with radius $\frac{mv}{qB}$.

Comment: *we cant mutually determine both the trajectory and momentum of a subatomic particle.* Is your particle subatomic? What's the range of the circle it is describing?

Comment: The equation you are proposing for the path of the electron is derived with classical physics. It doesn't hold for quantum mechanics.

Comment: I asked a possibly related question a few months ago: [How does the uncertainity principle apply in this situation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588174/how-does-the-uncertainity-principle-apply-in-this-situation)

Comment: @Roger it was taught in our class...so it came in my mind...thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

The uncertainty principle is true in a quantum mechanical framework. The problems you mention are instead in a classical framework and because of this Heisenberg's principle doesn't apply.

The fundamental reason why Heisenberg's principle is true in quantum mechanics is that in the quantum theory observables such as position and momentum are, mathematically, operators and not scalar quantities. As operators, they don't, in general, commute, which means $AB\neq BA$ in general for two operators $A$ and $B$. This is however not true in classical physics, where the product is always commutative.

Comment: feels like i dont have the pre requisites to understand this....anyways thanks for your effort;)

Comment: i dont know much about quantum mechanics so thats why...

Comment: Don't worry! If I can clarify something of my answer you can tell me and I'll try to explain it more clearly